# How to load .NET Core assemblies in unmanaged C++ and call functions etc?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mono

What I am looking for is something like Mono but for .NET Core. I heard that the .NET runtime does essentially what Mono does to .NET Framework.

My goal is to have some sort of DLL that is compiled from C# in .NET Core that I can call methods from in C++. This DLL should also be able to call the C++ functions (a bit like internal calls in Mono).

I am pretty new to any of the C# & C++ cross calling stuff like Mono, so I also have a question. When I compile a class library (a DLL) on Windows, would that DLL work on other platforms with either Mono or the .NET Core equivalent of it? If not do I have to compile separate DLLs for each of the different platforms?

Comment: To run any .Net code you need a runtime, this is possible [1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1276328/Hosting-NET-Core-Components-in-Unmanaged-C-Cpluspl) [2](https://dev.to/tvinko/control-net-runtime-from-native-code-473f). But likely more complicated than calling native code from .net. And *any* native/managed interface will cause a certain amount of 'friction'. If you provided some more context we might suggest if this is actually a good idea or not.

Comment: The managed code should run on any compatible plattform. The unmanaged code not. The native formats are different. A bit simplified in native/unmanaged code you would need a *.dll on windows, a *.dylib on macos and a *.so on linux. So on different plattforms you presumably need special builds of both sides as the unmanaged code differs.

Comment: You can host .NET Core CLR (or CoreCLR for short) in your C++ applications and bridge the two worlds, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting But whether a specific .NET assembly (class library) can work on all platforms depends on the logic written by its developer(s), not the runtime, nor how you compile the source code.